# != false vs. == true

Tags: performance, programming-languages, evaluation

I think I've read somewhere that the evaluation of negation (!= false) is faster than == true

Is this correct?

Comment: Don't know, but one never writes !=false or ==true anyway, one writes if(~x) or if(x) -- translate to the language(s) of your choice.

Comment: I imagine this is completely language (and implementation) specific.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: I think recently the trend goes just the opposite direction, because readability matters and there's no performance hit

Comment: @Cameron: even worse...it's chip specific and compiler specific. There have been chips where comparison to zero is faster than comparison to any non-zero value, and where the "easy" implementation of a compiler makes taking the "else" branch faster by one clock. So you can see how this got started on some chip with both these properties and a primitive compiler *(you can save two whole cycles!).* And then, cargo-cult-like, it just never dies...

Comment: Readability is precisely why you *shouldn't* write `!=false` nor `==true`.  `if(x)` / `if(!x)` are the canonical form, anything else is slower to read because it's out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's not correct. All modern compilers and interpreters will optimize that.

What matters (to me, at least) is that `== true` is much faster for ME to interpret.

Remember, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Edit: Yes, i use `if(true)`. But that was not the question.

Comment: But of course, `== true` is entirely redundant anyway, and can almost always be omitted.

Comment: -1: because in most language `if x == true` should not be used at all as `if x` does the same thing. It's just noise for the reader (that the compiler will optimize away).

Comment: @kriss Yeah, i agree with you but feketegy used "== true" so i wrote that to be clear on what i meant.

Comment: @kriss It is unfair to downvote because _"in most languages .."_, because the question is NOT language specific.

Comment: -1: never write `== true` - it's dangerous in C, C++ and related languages.

Comment: @kriss: That was not the question... it was != true or == false. +1 to balance that.

Comment: @Eiko: read the question again - you have it the wrong way round.

Comment: @Paul R: Sorry, other way around. Still, it was *not* the question to leave it out completely.

Comment: @belisarius: actually, I only know about 10 languages, but comparing a boolean value to true or false is not necessary in *any* of them. That is just making a show of not understanding what is a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not correct.

Except when dealing with `bool?` in .Net, you should never write either.
Instead, you should write `if (someBool)` or `if (!someBool)`.

Comment: Why is that? is it really faster?

Comment: It's only cleaner if your condition has a nice name.

Comment: @Eiko: Whether or not a variable has a nice name is another issue altogether. Using `if (missileReadyToLaunch)` is indeed more readable than `if (blah)`, but that *doesn't* mean that `if (blah)` isn't itself cleaner than `if (blah == true)`.

Comment: @LukeH: This may be true for many cases, but I've seen just too much bad code, and when you don't know it's a boolean value that you are checking (in many languages you can check almost anything with *if*), then comparing to true will give a very good hint on what to expect, and how to read that code.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things, and readability matters more. But which is it? How do we find out? We TEST it. To be fair we'll test an equal number of True and False values with ==True and !=False in Python:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> import time
>>> f=Timer('x=True;x!=False;x=False;x!=False',timer=time.clock)
>>> t=Timer('x=True;x==True;x=False;x==True',timer=time.clock)
>>> f.timeit(number=10000000)
3.2700000000000005
>>> t.timeit(number=10000000)
3.629999999999999
```

Now this is pretty consistent over a few timeit runs. Wow. Testing for !=False is quicker than testing ==True. If you have to do that 10,000,000 times you'll win half a second. Enjoy that time.

Comment: What's causing the difference?

Comment: The problem here is that True and false are too slow, just change `f=Timer('x=1;x!=0;x=0;x!=0',timer=time.clock)` and `t=Timer('x=1;x==1;x=0;x==1',timer=time.clock)` and the difference is about 1 sec

Comment: To find out why it is faster would mean compiling python with debugging and profiling and then looking at the profile output carefully. Any random hypotheses I've come up with seem to go the wrong way though (eg 'False' is longer than 'True' so should be slower to parse... nope...)..

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about it!

Any half-decent language will translate your high-level code into whatever low-level construct is fastest anyway.

Just use whichever construct produces the most readable code. And in most languages you don't even need to use an explicit comparision: if possible use `if (foo)` rather than `if (foo == true)` or `if (foo != false)`.

Answer (score 2):

Never, ever, test for `== true`, at least in `C`, `C++`, `Objective C` or related languages, where any non-zero value is *equivalent to* (but not necessarily *equal to*) true.

Acceptable:

```
if (x)
if (!x)
if (x == false)
if (x != false)
```

Wrong and dangerous:

```
if (x == true)
if (x != true)
```

The performance aspect is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I suspect that this is probably the root of the OP's misconception. Maybe they've read that using `!= false` is "better" than `== true` and misinterpreted "better" to mean "faster".

Comment: @LukeH: yes, I think you hit the nail on the head there !

Comment: I'd disagree with your listing, i find `x != false` to be a bit confusing, it's the same as `x`, i don't see any point in using a double negative. On the other hand `x != true` translates to `proposition is not true` which i don't mind at all.

Comment: @H.B.: I think you may have missed the point about why `x != true` is dangerous.

Comment: Could you please enlighten me then?

Comment: @H.B.: consider what happens if x has a value other then 0 or 1, e.g. If x = -1, then `if (x == false)` works as expected but `if (x != true)` doesn't.

Comment: Oh, thank you, i somehow got caught up in thinking about coding style there, this consideration normally does not matter for me since i do not program in any language where this can happen.